# change space between ticks in first y-axis in plt.imshow

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axes, imshow

Hey I have used the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

Class1=np.array([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.], [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.], [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.], [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.], [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.], [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.], [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.], [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.], [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.], [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.], [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.], [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.], [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.], [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.], [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.], [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.], [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.], [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.], [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.], [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], [1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1.], [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.], [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.], [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.], [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.], [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.], [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.], [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.], [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.], [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.], [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.], [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.], [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.], [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.], [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.], [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1.], [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0.]])

Unique=np.array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10., 11., 12.,
   13., 14., 15., 16., 17., 18., 19., 20., 21., 22., 23., 24., 25.,
   26., 27., 28., 29., 30., 31., 32., 33., 34., 35., 36., 37., 38.])
counts=np.array([56184982,  2904400,  4950837,   114746,     4270,   182052,
     844444,   106292,    47007,    68480,    23522,    13838,
      23990,   301704,    50462,    21345,    12263,     7217,
      64194,      251,      885,  2947045,  4895643,   102992,
       4401,   180136,   844872,      281,   107200,    48703,
      69791,    22651,    50295,    22772,     7020,    62543,
         43,     1103,       48])

list_y2=[]
list_x=[]
list_y1=[]
for i in np.arange(len(Unique)):
  list_y2.append( np.array2string(round(counts[i]/Class1.sum(axis=1)[i],2)))
  if i < 9:
    list_x.append(str(i+1))    
  else:
    list_x.append( str(i+1))
  list_y1.append( str(38-int(Unique[i])))

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
F=16
ax1.set_xlabel('Brain image',fontsize=F)
ax1.set_yticks(np.arange(len(list_y1)))
ax1.set_yticklabels(list_y1)
ax1.set_xticks(np.arange(len(list_x)))
ax1.set_xticklabels(list_x)  
ax1.set_ylabel('class',fontsize=F)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.set_yticks(np.arange(len(list_y2)))
ax2.set_yticklabels(list_y2, va='baseline')
ax2.set_ylabel('size',fontsize=F)
#Rotate the tick labels and set their alignment.
plt.setp(ax1.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha="right",
     rotation_mode="anchor")
plt.imshow(Class1, aspect='auto')
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

which makes the following plot:

[image: plot]

The problem with this is that the first y-axis doesn't fit the plot properly. The length between the ticks in the first y-axis should be the same as in the second y-axis and the 0 in the top and the 38 in bottom should be moved a bit inward on the y-axis. Hope one of you can help me.

Comment: Your code can't run because you use variables which are not defined before.

Comment: You can also easily make this into a (much much more) minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I have edited the code, so you should be able to run it now. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: The code you provided now plots a different figure than the one in your question. The difference is in the x and y axes ticklabels.

Comment: Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem recently and found the following workaround: Setting the same limits for the twin axis `ax2` as for the parent axis (`ax1`). This aligns the ticks on both y-axes and then you proceed by setting the ticks and the labels as desired as you are doing.

```
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.set_ylim(ax1.get_ylim()) # This was the fix for me
ax2.set_yticks(np.arange(len(list_y2)))
ax2.set_yticklabels(list_y2, va='baseline')
ax2.set_ylabel('size',fontsize=F)
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: I changed ax1.set_ylim(-0.5,38.5), which was the limit for the second y axis and now it works perfectly, thanks :-)